# Send job status from a table in azure as email

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a table in Azure called Job Status which is a small table, row size of 15. I would like to send entire row as email  to users from this table.

I tried logic app in azure but each email corresponds to one row only. I want a single email with all the rows formatted as a table.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a logic app
2. Add a trigger based on records count or by time
3. Add an action that calls Azure function for email. You can use  NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extensions.SendGrid.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried logic app in azure but each email corresponds to one row only.

If you create "Get entities" action and just send email you can find it will create a foreach action, that's because Dynamic content only can get entity one by one.

[image]

**So you could create a csv table after Get Entities like the pic shows.**
[image]

In my situation I got an error:

> InvalidTemplate. The execution of template action 'Create_CSV_table'
>   failed. The column values could not be evaluated: 'The template
>   language expression 'item()['additionalProperties']' cannot be
>   evaluated because property 'additionalProperties' doesn't exist,
>   available properties are 'odata.etag, PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp,
>   Email, PhoneNumber'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for
>   usage details.'.

If you occur same problem, you could click **Code view**, the delete the `additionalProperties` part or you could change the keyword to other properties name you want to show in the mail. 
[image]
[image]

After these the mail would like the pic content.

[image]

Hope this could help you. If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: @Sulfikkar B S if my answer is helpful, you could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAet0.png)

I could resolve the issue using recurrence,execute a sql query,create html table,and send an email.Recurrence is basically schedule,execute a sql would fetch rows from a table,create html table would do creating excel table in html format,and then send the email